# How do I override a Magento Controller (uppercase C)?

Tags: magento, overriding

I know how to override controllers, blocks and such, but not how to override a Magento controller with uppercase C like **Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice**. How would I override that class in my module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Files in "Controller" folders are usually abstract classes for stuff inside the "controllers" folder. So what you should probably do is to override the class "*Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_InvoiceController*" which in turn extends the "*Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice*" class.

Magento has no real knowledge about classes in the "Controller" folders and that's why you can not override them with XML. The class that extends them is relying on the autoloader to find them, and the folder name could have been anything.